# Pro*C syntax with select in select

Tags: syntax, proc

Why won't this compile?

```
EXEC SQL insert into ssa (id )  
    select ( select max(id)      
        from ss s   
        where s.id = t.id )        
    from temp_sca   t      
    where not exists      
        (select null      
        from sca ssa 2      
        where ssa2.ss_id = (    select max (id)         
                from ss   s         
               where s.x = t.ss_id )      
               and ssa2.x = t.x )
```

Error I get:

select ( select max ( id)
 ...................1
    PCC-D-02201, Encountered the symbol "max" when expecting one fo the following:

```
( ) * + ...
```

The symbol "(" was substituted for "max" to continue

Can we not embed a select in the select clause in Pro*C?
 Oracle 11g on Solaris 10

Or is there a work-around?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe a dynamic sql statement may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, converted the before mentioned to a dynamic sql c-string, then did an EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on the resulting sql/c string, and all is well.  Hopefully someone else may find this solution helpful.

Answer (score 0):

MAX function is used here and MAX should be used with a GROUP BY. So, when Pro*C compiler tries to compile this, it does not find a GROUP BY and throwing this compilation error.